# get pubCenter eCPM via some API?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am wondering if it is possible to get current pubCenter eCPM via some kind of API?

There is a WindowsPhone app called "PubCenter Adviser", and it displays current eCPM for all pubCenter categories.

How did they make it?
Is there any API so I can get the data from?
If solution exists - can someone provide a link to any documentation or similar stuff?

I've searched google and found nothing :(

kind regards,
maciej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How did they make it?

You'd have to ask them.

> Is there any API so I can get the data from?

There is no **documented** API. Still, it's more than likely that an API is available: on the pubcenter page, the graphs are displayed using Silverlight. A quick look at the HTML code of the page shows that the data isn't provided directly to the Silverlight app:

```
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="source" value="ClientBin/AdvancedReport.xap"/>
        <param name="onerror" value="OnSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="2.0.31005.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <param name="uiculture" value="en-US" />
        <param name="culture" value="en-US" />
        <param name="initParams" value="LogFlushThreshold=1,TraceLevel=Verbose,LogServiceUrl=/Shared/Services/LogService.svc,LocaleId=en-us,IsMobileOnlyUser=True,WebMobileAlertMessage=Note: Click data is for websites only" />
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none"/>
        </a>
    </object>
```

It means that, once loaded, the Silverlight app will call some kind of service to get the data. But to know which service is called and with what parameters, you'll have to reverse-engineer the app (either by decompiling the XAP, or by monitoring the HTTP requests with Fiddler).